# Synchronized methods and locks

Tags: java

When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object and releases it when the method returns but what happens when a static synchronized method is invoked because  a static method is associated with a class  not an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every classes and interface in java has an associated object.

For a class name MyClass,  you can get the class object by

```
MyClass.class
```

From any object obj, you can get the class object by

```
obj.getClass()
```

The lock is obtained for this object when a static method is synchronized.

Answer (score 5):

A class is an Object too. When invoking synchronized static method, you acquire a lock on Class object.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear- that still means, for example, one thread executes a synchronized nonstatic method, while the other does synchronized static method. You just cannot have two threads execute 2 synchronized static methods at the same time.